# How to work out difference between H:i times on a 24 hour clock?

Tags: php, datetime, time

I am creating something that calculates fees based on the duration of a nightly event. Sometimes these events go over into the early hours of the following morning.

I have a table in my database that looks similar to this (just so you can see how the dates are formatted):

```
Start Time        Finish Time
23:30             00:00
21:00             01:30
20:00             22:00
```

There is no date or timestamp attached to any of these times. It is assumed that if the Finish Time is "earlier" on a 24 hour clock then it must be the day after.

I am lost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the finish time is less than the start time, add 24:00 to the finish time and do the calculation.

Comment: So simple. Thank you!